# configure winston to not send logs on newrelic

Tags: node.js, logging, newrelic, winston

I want to configure my winston logger in such a way that for localhost it should not send logs to newrelic.

```
export const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
  transports: [
    // Other transports
    new transports.Console(),  ],
  exitOnError: false
});
```

now, if I log anything using this logger it will automatically send logs to newrelic.

```
logger.info('This will be sent to newrelic')
```

I want to have an option if I'm in localhost this logger should work for all other transports but should not send logs to newrelic.

Something like this

```
export const logger = createLogger({
  format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
  transports: [
    // Other transports
    new transports.Console(),  ],
  exitOnError: false
});
if(process.env.NODE_ENV=='localhost'){
//configure winston to not log on newrelic
}
```

and when I do this after it should not log on newrelic

```
logger.info('This should not sent to newrelic')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that you did and found two solutions:

1. Disable winston for development like:

```
logger: process.env.NODE_ENV==='localhost' ? ['verbose'] : logger,
```

2. Update your `newrelic.js` to have production and development version, where elogs are disabled for development.